# ActionScript 3 Undefined property

Tags: actionscript-3, properties, undefined

I have been playing around with Shared Objects trying to understand how they operate. In this basic practical example I am opting for the sharedObject.getRemote instead of using getLocal because I'm using Flash Media Server. I have updated the value of some data in the setProperty method() then if that data exists I try to retrieve it from the data property. When I run the application the output panel should be reading:

```
paris
250
true
```

However, it states access of undefined property. Can you please look at the code and tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
import flash.net.NetConnection;
import flash.events.NetStatusEvent;
import flash.net.SharedObject;
import flash.events.SyncEvent;

var nc:NetConnection = new NetConnection();

nc.connect("rtmfp://localhost/sobjExample");

nc.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, netHandler);

function netHandler(event:NetStatusEvent):void{
    switch(event.info.code){
    case "NetConnection.Connect.Success":
    trace("Connected Up");
    break;

    case "NetConnection.Connect.Close":
    trace("Closing time");
    break;

    case "NetConnection.Connect.Failed":
    trace("Whoops");
    break;

    case "NetConnection.Connect.Rejected":
    trace("Ouch!!!!!");
    break;
        }
}

var so:SharedObject = SharedObject.getRemote("city", nc.uri, true);

so.connect(nc);

so.addEventListener(SyncEvent.SYNC, seeSo);

 function seeSo(event:SyncEvent):void{
    trace(so.changeList[0].code);
    switch(so.changeList[0].code){
        case "clear":
        loadSo();
        break;

        case "Success":
        showSo();
        break;
    }


}

function loadSo():void{
    so.setProperty("city", "Paris");
    so.setProperty("bunch", "250");
}       so.setProperty("verity", "true");

function showSo():void{
    trace(so.data.city);
    trace(so.data.bunch);
}       trace(so.data.verity);
```

Comment: I do not understand the problem,¿what is the line with the error? where are the undefined property?

Comment: Hi Gaston, Sorry for not providing you with all the information. When I run the program I receive two line errors. trace(so.changeList[0].code);and switch(so.changeList[0].code){ The compile error states: Scene 1, 1119: Access of possibly undefined property changeList through a reference with static type flash.net:SharedObject. I have altered my code numerous times but this annoying error keeps popping up. What should I do?

Comment: Are you using flex builder 3 or flash builder 4.x? Can you debug a code?, because you can evaluate the expression **so** (to see what's inside), i suppose that, if you run this **so.hasOwnProperty("changeList")**, it returns **false**

Comment: Hi Gaston, Sorry for my late reply. I am using Flash cs6. I already debugged the code it only gives me the same error has in the output. I feel so stupid that I cant fix this. I copied some of the code from a tutorial I read http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=kh9ibvQLTB4C&pg=PA70&lpg=PA70&dq=shared+object+changeList+array&source=bl&ots=9Xo0FlSYMa&sig=si0KMSjhZdBTHfvUbCTInbtuFdc&hl=en&sa=X&ei=UmWyUYq0FOvP0AWj-4DQCA&ved=0CD4Q6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=shared%20object%20changeList%20array&f=false anymore suggestions before I give up.